# MongoDB: Many to Many - When to implement with denormalized vs normalized?

Tags: mongodb

It seems to me that there are two ways to implement Many to Many relationships in MongoDB, normalized or denormalized, both of which have trade offs. How do I decide which model to implement? The remainder of this OP explains the trade offs with examples.

Take a Product to Sku relationship. One product has many skus, and each sku may be associated with many products. (I do not intend the answer of this question to be specific to this example, but rather any arbitrary Many to Many relationship).

**Normalized**

In a normalized model, there are two collections, product and sku. Each Document in both collections contains an array of (object)ids pointing to the other collection.

Pros:

- Data is not duplicated
- Prevents update/insert/deletion anomalies (except for the foreign key array)
- Finding a distinct list of skus is not expensive

Cons:

- Modifications to two separate documents are not atomic
- Finding the skus for a given product, or the reverse, requires two queries to the DB.
- Foreign keys are not enforced, lending it self to anomalies (but only in the foreign key array)

E.g.,

```
db.store.sku.insert({
    'sku_id': 1,
    'name': 'cheese',
    'price': 0.50,
    'products': [10]
})
db.store.sku.insert({
    'sku_id': 2,
    'name': 'beef paddy',
    'price': 0.25,
    'products': [10]
})
db.store.product.insert({
    'product_id': 10,
    'name': 'cheese burger',
    'skus': [1, 2]
});
db.store.product.insert({
    'product_id': 11,
    'name': 'hamburger',
    'skus': [2]
});
```

**Denormalized**

In a denormalized model, there is one collection. Each document in the collection contains an array of documents.

Pros:

- Modifications to the single document is atomic
- Finding the skus for a given product, or the reverse, requires only one query to the db.

Cons:

- Data is duplicated
- Lends itself to update/insert/deletion anomalies
- Finding a distinct list of skus is expensive (I am presuming that db.store.product.distinct(skus) is relatively expensive)

E.g.,

```
db.store.product.insert({
    'product_id': 10,
    'name': 'cheese burger',
    'skus': [
         {
             'sku_id': 1,
             'name': 'cheese',
             'price': 0.50,
         },
         {
             'sku_id': 2,
             'name': 'beef paddy',
             'price': 0.25,
         }
     ]
});
db.store.product.insert({
    'product_id': 11,
    'name': 'hamburger',
    'skus': [
         {
             'sku_id': 2,
             'name': 'beef paddy',
             'price': 0.25,
         }
     ]
});
```

It would be important to note that there are some hybrid models, where the most often queried attributes and/or least likely to be changed attributes are stored in the denormalized collection, and all other attributes are stored in a reference collection.

How does one decide which method to implement a many to many relationship in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you call "Denormalized" is just plain wrong for your problem scope, since you're storing different, but equivalent "sku" subdocuments that are not related in the data structure. Having two different "sku_id":2 fields would be just fine, like two blog posts can both have a "first" comment by different users, but in your scenario it isn't. If you allow broken states in your data model you're in serious trouble even before you start.

Your "Normalized" approach is better, but still not correct for your scenario. Your data modeling implies that the relationship between products and SKUs is (in terms of graphs) a directed edge, meaning a product can refer to a SKU without the SKU referring back to the product.

I can think of two correct modeling approaches for that: Either you just reference the SKU in the product and just don't have a reference back, since it's implicitly there. If you need a way from SKU to product list, I  suggest building a query and probably an index for that, but pretty please don't double link this. Second approach is the SQL n:m approach: have a set of documents that only contain information about this relationship. But honestly, I think unless you're running some very serious operations on that very link between products and SKUs, this would be as bad as it would be correct.

Oh and for foreign key constraints: There is no such thing in MongoDB. There isn't even a place where you could define such a thing, since there is no schema definition.